# Timer and dependancy injection

Tags: ios, swift

I've just started with Swift and using MVVM with dependency injection.

In my ViewModel I have Timer that handles refreshing the data. I've simplified the code a little for clarity.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let viewModel = ViewModel()
    }
}

class ViewModel: NSObject {

    private var timer: Timer?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setUpTimer()
    }

    func setUpTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true){_ in
            self.refreshData()
        }
    }

    func refreshData() {
        //refresh data
        print("refresh data")
    }
}
```

I want to use dependency injection to pass the Timer into the ViewModel so that I can control the timer when doing unit tests and make it call immediately.

So passing the Timer is pretty simple. How can I pass a Timer in to ViewModel that has the ability to call the refreshData() belonging to ViewModel. Is there a trick in Swift that allows this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true){_ in
            // call refreshData() from the class ViewModel
            }

        var viewModel = ViewModel(myTimer:timer)
    }
}

class ViewModel: NSObject {

    private var timer: Timer?

    init(myTimer:Timer) {
        super.init()
        //setUpTimer()
        timer = myTimer
    }

    func refreshData() {
        //refresh data
        print("refresh data")
    }
}
```

I thought it might be possible using the scheduelTimer that takes a selector instead of a block but that would require using a @objc before the func refreshData() which seems clunky since I am using an Objective C feature in Swift.

Is there a nice way to achieve this?

Many Thanks,
Code

Comment: What do you want to test here: that `ViewModel` refreshes itself periodically and you want to control that refresh frequency during your test?

Comment: You "could" write a proxy/builder class which is passed to the view model, the view model would then use it to build the physical timer - or at least "register" for timed updates - how it works would be unimportant to view model.  Then you could mock this proxy/builder

Comment: *"seems clunky since I am using an Objective C feature in Swift."* - Since almost all the core API is written mostly in ObjC, you're always using ObjC in some way or another - Swift just exposes nice "swifty" wrappers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, you want to decouple the implementation.  So instead of having to pass `Timer` to the view model, you pass some other "control" object, which guarantees to perform the operation (of calling back after a delay)

If that doesn't shout `protocol`, I don't know what does...

```
typealias Ticker = () -> Void

protocol Refresher {
    var isRunning: Bool { get }
    func register(_ ticker: @escaping Ticker)
    func start();
    func stop();
}
```

So, pretty basic concept.  It can start, stop and an observer can register itself to it and be notified when a "tick" occurs.  The observer doesn't care "how" it works, so long as it guarantees to perform the specified operation.

A `Timer` based implementation then might look something like...

```
class TimerRefresher: Refresher {

    private var timer: Timer? = nil
    private var ticker: Ticker? = nil

    var isRunning: Bool = false

    func register(_ ticker: @escaping Ticker) {
        self.ticker = ticker
        guard timer == nil else {
            return
        }
    }

    func start() {
        guard ticker != nil else {
            return
        }
        stop()
        isRunning = true
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.tick()
        })
    }

    func stop() {
        guard let timer = timer else {
            return
        }
        isRunning = false
        timer.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }

    private func tick() {
        guard let ticker = ticker else {
            stop()
            return
        }
        ticker()
    }
}
```

This provides you the entry point for mocking the dependency injection, by replacing the implementation of the `Refresher` with one you can control manually (or use a different "delaying" action, depending on your needs)

This is just a conceptual example, your implementation/needs may differ and lead you to a slightly different design, but the idea remains the same, decouple the physical implementation in some way.

An alternative would require you to rethink your design, and instead of the view model performing it's own refresh, the view/controller would take over that responsibility instead. Since that's a significant design decision, you're really only the person who can make that decision, but it's another idea

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want the model to refresh every 30 seconds when running in the app, but faster for test. If so, don't inject the Timer. Inject the refresh frequency.

```
class ViewModel: NSObject {
    // We need something to observe and confirm that the data is fresh
    @objc dynamic var lastRefreshed: Date?

    private var timer: Timer!

    // The default frequency is 30 seconds but users can adjust that
    // The unit test uses it to inject dependency
    init(refreshFrequency: TimeInterval = 30) {
        super.init()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: refreshFrequency, target: self, selector: #selector(refreshData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func refreshData() {
        lastRefreshed = Date()
        print("refreshed on: \(lastRefreshed!)")
    }
}
```

And your unit test:

```
func testModel() {
    let startTime = Date()
    let model = ViewModel(refreshFrequency: 5)

    // Test first refresh: must be within 5 - 6 seconds from startTime
    keyValueObservingExpectation(for: model, keyPath: #keyPath(ViewModel.lastRefreshed)) { (_, _) -> Bool in
        if let duration = model.lastRefreshed?.timeIntervalSince(startTime), 5...6 ~= duration {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    // Test second refresh: must be within 10 - 12 seconds from startTime
    keyValueObservingExpectation(for: model, keyPath: #keyPath(ViewModel.lastRefreshed)) { (_, _) -> Bool in
        if let duration = model.lastRefreshed?.timeIntervalSince(startTime), 10...12 ~= duration {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    // Wait 12 seconds for both expectations to be fulfilled
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 12, handler: nil)
}
```

`Timer` is not exact: it does not fire exactly every 5 seconds like you asked. Apple say `Timer` is accurate to about 50 - 100ms. Hence we cannot expect that the first refresh will happen 5 seconds from now. We must allow for some tolerances. The further out you go, the bigger this tolerance have to become.